# In plm, unexpected difference between model = "within" on pre-differenced variable and model = "fd"?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I am fitting a diff-in-diff model on panel data with multiple treatment windows using the plm package.

In the plm package, there are options to set:
  - model = "within" vs model = "fd" (first difference).

Why dont the following produce equivalent coefficient estimates:
  - a regression with model = "within" when my variable is already differenced `$Y_\textit{diff} = (Y_{t_i} - Y_{t_{i-1}})$`,
  - a regression with model = `fd` when my variable is untransformed `$Y_{t_i}$`,

I cannot quite understand why the estimates are not identical:

- Why might this be happening?
- What is the correct use of the "model" parameter and, crucially:

  - when should *model = `fd` be used vs *model = `within` (especially, when dealing with "change variables" `$Y_\textit{diff}$` on the LHS)
  - In your opinion, which of the two would be most appropriate here and how would you decide?
- Finally, why are "twoway" fixed effects no longer allowed when using *model = "fd"*

#### Some background

In case it may be relevant, here is a high-level description of the current panel:

1. I am currently using Panel Data that spans 27 years at the county/district level
2. Counties are clustered into groups for the entire window (non-random assignment, e.g. urban/rural)
3. It is a repeated measures design. Every few years, treatment occurs at the group level by random assignment - where all entities in a particular group either receive Treatment-X or Treatment-Y.
4. While entities are not randomly assigned to groups, **treatment is randomly assigned.**
5. Each of the two groups undergoes 2 exposures to Treatment-X and 2 exposures to Treatment-Y over the course of the entire time window, resulting in 4 pre-post measures.

#### Code and Sample Outputs

The code and outputs are included below. As you can see, the estimate for the diff-in-diff term for the model specified using "first difference" is quite different from the estimate for the diff-in-diff term for the model specified using "within" - even though the "within" models are run after differencing the Y variable. And, it does not matter whether the effects are specified at the "individual-level" or "two way"

To facilitate accurate statistical tests, we rely upon the *lmtest* and *sandwich* packages to produce standard errors that are robust to clustering at county-level using a helper function (code shown at the end).

**Regression #1 - First-Difference & Individual Fixed Effects:**

*Regression on Y with *model = "fd" | Effects: Individual*

*Note: effect = "two-way" is not allowed for first difference models*

```
PLM__Y__model.FD__effect.individual <-
  plm(Y ~  Pre.Post.Treatment * Treatment.or.Control
      , data=Panel, index=c("GEOID", "Year")
      , model="fd", effect = "individual")

get.coef.test.with.clustered.SEs(PLM__Y__model.FD__effect.individual)
```

**Regression #2 - Model Within  & Two-way Fixed Effects on Y.diff:**

*Regression on Y.diff with *model = "within"* | Effects: Two-Way*

```
PLM__diff.Y__model.within__effect.individual <-
  plm(diff.Y ~  Pre.Post.Treatment * Treatment.or.Control
      , data=Panel, index=c("GEOID", "Year")
      , model="within", effect = "twoways")

get.coef.test.with.clustered.SEs(PLM__diff.Y__model.within__effect.individual)
```

**Regression #3 - Model Within  & Individual Fixed Effects on Y.diff:** 
*Regression on Y.diff with *model = "within"* | Effects: Individual*

```
PLM__diff.Y__model.within__effect.individual <-
  plm(diff.Y ~  Pre.Post.Treatment * Treatment.or.Control
      , data=Panel, index=c("GEOID", "Year")
      , model="within", effect = "individual")

get.coef.test.with.clustered.SEs(PLM__diff.Y__model.within__effect.individual)
```

[Regression Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPcud.png)

I expected regressions run on differenced variables `$Y_\textit{diff} = (Y_{t_i} - Y_{t_{i-1}})$ using model="within"` to produce the same estimates or standard errors as the panel regressions run with `$Y_{t_i}$ using model ="fd"`